# Babel in Basque

Tags: installing, babel

I am new to this and I would like to get what's needed to use Babel in basque.
I've tried `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-basque`, emulating an answer in this site but it doesn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated.

the code I am trying is this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[Basque]{babel}

\begin{document}

euskeraz ari naiz idazten

\end{document}
```

and this is what the terminal shows:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)

 restricted \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode

(./exponential.tex

LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>

Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls

Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty

! Package babel Error: Language definition file Basque.ldf not found.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.

Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

 ...                                              

l.141 \ProcessOptions*

?
```

Comment: What operating system are you using and what version?

Comment: egreg, I am using Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Is your OS case-sensitive? Try `basque` instead of `Basque` (the lowercased name is the proper syntax, anyway).

Comment: I tried that Javier Bezos, and it didn't work

Comment: I've been not able to find where is Basque support in http://packages.debian.org :( I'll try again.

Comment: any help is greatly appreciated egreg!

Comment: @WilliamNeill I can only tell you to try texlive-lang-other, although Basque is not listed explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ubuntu 13.04 the basque language definition files are in the package texlive-lang-french. Don't ask me why :-) After Installing this package and changing `Basque` to `basque` your example should work.

Comment: dude, that was awesome!

Comment: how did you get to know this?

Comment: somebody up vote this ;)

Comment: I looked in several of the `texlive-lang-?` packages, but not the one for French. Good catch!

Comment: @WilliamNeill I am Basque so I use this package since long ago. I remember having the same problems some years ago; I can't tell how I found it. Probably, by inspection of the files installed by each `texlive-lang` package.